# Move Term in Equation Out of Summation

Tags: equations, formatting

I have the following equation:

```
\begin{bmatrix}
    \sum \limits _{0 \leq i \lt m-1}
        \begin{pmatrix}
            q_i - \mu_Q^{(i+1)}
        \end{pmatrix} ^2
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
   q_{m-1} - \mu_Q^{(m)}
\end{pmatrix} ^2
```

[image]

Notice that the term that is outside of the square bracket should not be included in the summation on the left as it does not depend on `i`. However, I would like to remove the square brackets and keep the last term on the right. Unfortunately, it now looks like this:

[image]

Now it looks like the last term is a part of the summation (which is wrong). Is there a way to keep the order as shown but visually move the last term out of the summation without using brackets? I could move the last term in front of the summation but the visual ordering matters in my case.

Comment: There's no need to use matrices to begin with.

Comment: Given the fact that the last term does not depend on `i` it is clear that is is not a part of the sum. And as egreg mentions, why are you using matrices here? Matrices have a different meaning than just braces.

Comment: Sorry, I am fairly new to LaTeX and just grabbed a convenient way to draw larger, encompassing brackets to show groupings. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Looks like I should be using `\left` and `\right` instead

Answer (score 2):

The standard mathematical parsing rules say that

[image]

should be interpreted as “first do the summation of the *x*<sub>*i*</sub> terms and then add *y*”, differently from

[image]

where there would be *m* summands equal to *y*.

If you want to be extra sure that your reader will not interpret wrongly the expression, either change the order or use parentheses, I see no other way. The top display in the image below is what I'd use.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\sum_{0\le i\le m-1} (q_i - \mu_Q^{(i+1)}) + (q_{m-1} - \mu_Q^{(m)})
\]
\[
\biggl(\,\sum_{0\le i\le m-1} (q_i - \mu_Q^{(i+1)})\biggr) + (q_{m-1} - \mu_Q^{(m)})
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't use `matrix` (or variants thereof) instead of parentheses.